# floats in inline assembly x86-64

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I compile this code on my mac (i7 Core) x86-64:

```
int float_asm(float x) {
    int result;

    asm ("ucomiss %[zero], %[x]\n\t"
         "movl $2, %[result]\n\t"
         "movl $3, %%esi\n\t"
         "cmovpl %%esi, %[result]"
    : [result] "=r" (result)
    : [zero] "x" (0), [x] "x" (x)
    : "cc", "rsi");
    return result;
}
```

I have some questions to it:

1. is there other way to pass float immediate to inline assembly?
2. I used "x" constrain to pass float immediate and float var which lets gcc find most optimal option. Is there a way to be more specific when it comes to floating points (like "r" and "i" for integers)?

Comment: Did you try adding a size suffix? e.g. `cmovpl`?

Comment: `cmov` doesn't accept an immediate operand.

Comment: @Michael thanks, it worked

Comment: I usually find it more efficient to minimize the size of the asm block and allow the compiler to do as much of the work as possible. Maybe: `asm ("ucomiss %[zero], %[x]\n\t" "cmovpl %[esi], %[result]" : [result] "=r" (result) : [zero] "x" (0), [x] "x" (x), "[result]" (2), [esi] "r" (3) : "cc");`? While this might look the same, consider `float_asm(1.1) + float_asm(2.2)`. How many times do we have to load [esi]? And this lets the compiler pick the best reg. And when we are done, the compiler knows that [esi] contains the value '3' in case it wants to do something else with that value later.

Comment: BTW, isn't parity only set if x is NAN?  Couldn't you just use isnan (from math.h) and omit the whole asm?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd yeah, it checks for NAN. I'm just practicing my inline assembly skills

Comment: Nothing wrong with practicing (I sure do!). But in my experience, inline asm frequently turns out to be a bad idea. Don't get me wrong: It's cool, powerful, gives insight into how the compiler works, etc. But IRL it's non-portable (both to other hw and other compilers), hard to maintain, hard to get right and can (easily) produce worse code than plain old c. That said, gcc6 [allows](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#FlagOutputOperands): `asm ("ucomiss %[zero], %[x]" : "=@ccp" (res) : [zero] "x" (0), [x] "x" (x) : "cc"); if (res) return 3; else return 2;`. How cool is that?